# Run multiple vbscripts to install software sequentially

Tags: vbscript

I know very little scripting but have 4 separate scripts to install 4 programs (runas pro + software to install software without the need for local admin rights)

How do i combine the 4 scripts into one script to install each software after the previous one has completed?

Here are my basic 4 scripts:

`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN("RunAsP.exe Adobe Air.rap")
Set objShell = Nothing`

`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN("RunAsP.exe FrameWork 4.rap")
Set objShell = Nothing`

`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN("RunAsP.exe Visual Studio runtime.rap")
Set objShell = Nothing`

`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN("RunAsP.exe SalesForce For Outlook.rap")
Set objShell = Nothing`

Any help would be much appreciated as i'm all googled out after having tried numerous methods)

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc that references the "run" method of WSHShell:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx

To fix your script you'd want something like this (note I fixed some syntax errors and other bugs in your script, not just the problem you were looking to solve.)

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "RunAsP.exe Adobe Air.rap", 0, True
objShell.run "RunAsP.exe FrameWork 4.rap", 0, True
objShell.run "RunAsP.exe Visual Studio runtime.rap", 0, True
objShell.run "RunAsP.exe SalesForce For Outlook.rap", 0, True
Set objShell = Nothing
```

bWaitOnReturn: 
Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to true, script execution halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).

Comment: Arguments need quoting.

Comment: Much appreciated Nathan - i tried using the 0, true but it failed but will give yours a go

Comment: Script appears to run all 4 applications at once using the above?!. Script working ok however when runasp.exe removed from the equation (test computer with local admin rights). Any suggestions?